# Binary to String trouble

Tags: java, text, binary

Hi
I'm trying to write a program that coverts a binary entered by the user into a string of text. I have hit a roadblock of sorts i can get my program to covert "01110110" to "v" but once i try something like "0110100001101001" it gives me symbols instead of the word "hi". Below is the source code that I'm using.
P.s Thanks for you help still trying to get a grasp of Java.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;




public class Binarytotext
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {

            String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter binary");
            int charCode = Integer.parseInt(b,2);
            String k = new Character((char)charCode).toString();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,k);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string has more than 8 bits in it, you need to break it down and parse each 8-bit segment independently, like:

```
int charCode;
String k = "";
String b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter binary");
while (b.length > 8) {
    charCode = Integer.parseInt(b.substring(0, 8),2);
    k += new Character((char)charCode).toString();
    b = b.substring(8);
}
if (b.length() > 0) {
    //attempt handle any trailing bits that might be left
    charCode = Integer.parseInt(b,2);
    k += new Character((char)charCode).toString();
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,k);
```

Comment: Nice working solution, but I can't upvote this because you are using String concatenation in loops, which is the ultimate evil

Comment: @Sean - Only when dealing with large strings or a large number of loop iterations.  For a simple example like this there is no practical difference.  Besides, the OP is trying to learn the basics of Java, so it might not be as helpful if I were to transform his code any more than strictly required to solve the problem.  Performance optimization lessons can come later.

Answer (score 3):

You are converting the whole sequence of 16 0s and 1s into a single integer.  You need to first split it into 8 character substrings (each 8 bits is one byte and each byte is one ASCII character).

Comment: Thank you that fixed part of my problem now just trying to figure out how to have my program accept the spaces without blowing up in my face.lol

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter binary");
String out = "";
while (input.length() >= 8) {
    out += (char) Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, 8), 2);
    input = input.substring(8);
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, out);
```